# Android java take screenshot from dialog box

Tags: java, android, screenshot, android-alertdialog

After a lot of research I found the solution to take screenshots when a dialog box is displaying:

```
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Title ...")
                .setMessage("Message ...")
                .setPositiveButton("Okay", null)
                .setNegativeButton("Screenshot", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                View displayView = AlertDialog.class.cast(dialog).getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
                                displayView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(displayView.getDrawingCache());
                                displayView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                               // ... processing the bitmap
                    }
                })
                .show();
```

However, the problem with this approach is that the dialog box on the screenshot is surrounded with a black background the size of the screen, which I suppose is his rootView.

How can I take screenshot **only** from the dialog box, or with other words - how can I reference its view?